# Quotes for single letters

Tags: punctuation

[image]

The title is clever describing 2 presidents during the transition but what I don't understand is the need to put in quotes "I's" If we assume that someone used the word transition therefore it could be in quotes I can understand that. Basically, the whole thing is confusing.

Maybe there is logic to this title but I need help with understanding its punctuation.

Comment: It's standard usage to put a word in quotes if you are referring to it as a word and not the thing it stands for. The same applies to single letters.

Comment: @Kate Do you have something to back that up? In my experience, it is _not_ common to consider single letters quotes; the quote from ODO in k1eran’s answer below writes it the way I’ve nearly always seen it written. The way it’s written in the MSNBC title here looks decidedly odd to me—especially since it’s not quoting the _letter_, but the _word_ that is the plural of the letter. If it were quoting the single letter, it would be _“I”’s_ (which looks equally ridiculous, of course).

Answer (score 1):

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe says:

> There are one or two cases in which it is acceptable to use an apostrophe to form a plural, purely for the sake of clarity:
>   you can use an apostrophe to show the plurals of single letters:
>   *I've dotted the i's and crossed the t's.*
>   *Find all the p's in appear.*
>   [...].

So, I read this as implying the caption should treat *I* as a letter :

> There are two I's in "transition".

Possibly one could argue these versions are ok:

> There are two "I"s in "transition".

> There are two *I*s in *transition*.

I think both the double quotes and the apostrophe together is a mess.

Comment: That’s not what the question is about.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet added some more text which is hopefully now more focused on the question!

Comment: Downvote retracted! I’d say it’s not so much the combination of quotes and apostrophe that makes it a mess in itself, but the fact that putting the quotes **around** _I’s_ makes it a quote of the pluralised form, rather than a quote of the single letter.